# How to show "field-image" in search page?

Tags: entities, media, search

I want make a photo gallery with Drupal.
I have a problem with showing article images (that shows in homepage in a div classed "field-image"), I want show this image is search page.
After searching for something just title and text shows, how to show images there?
Thanks a lot :)
look at this shots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, Have you tried anything for the same?

Comment: go to manage display and select the image preset for teaser display in select list.

Comment: @Bala that affected homepage, not search page.

Comment: @Ma3x it should affect all places where teasers are used. What display is used on your search results page?

Comment: @Mołot First post edited

Comment: Hint - use FireShot extension or similar tool to only grab relevant parts of page (or whole page, but without browser's controls). That way you are not wasting vertical space of a question on your toolbars. Also, try to narrow browser's window to 600px width if possible, as currently max-width of images is set to 630px, and when you post larger ones, scaling kicks in making them harder to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14471/drupal-7-displaying-an-image-to-search-results

Comment: @arpitr even if they are, the old one looks worse than this with screenshots and clear description. And I can't see how answers on old one are really useful :( If anything, it should be closed as off-opic: bugreport, both this and the old one.

Comment: @arpitr [meta question here](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2739/16495)

Comment: @Mołot thanks man :) i use awesome screenshot plus and first post edited again.

Comment: No problem, just a bit of guidance. But have you seen a link by @arpitr? It might be a deeper problem, not quite answerable (as it needs a bugfix, not an answer, if he's right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using default core search, you can modify "Search result" display there.

Comment: Yes! I use defualt core search module, see at first post, screen shots :)

Comment: Sorry for a bad first attempt :) If you don't want to write any code, the best option for you would be [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) integration with Core Search. Here is a [screencast](http://goo.gl/I9uypl)

Comment: thanks all :)
using Display Suite module i fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the search-result.tpl.php file and add some logic in your form pre-processing page (template.php), but all of this is quite a bit of work when you could rather just use the [Display Suite Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).

1. Install the module.
2. Enable "Display Suite", "Display Suite Search" and "Display Suite UI".
3. Enable "Display Suite Search" on the search settings page: /admin/config/search/settings
4. Go to a searched term page: search/content/SEARCH_STRING
5. You should now see a lot more info. As a final step, you can edit what is shown here by going to the settings page here: admin/structure/ds/list/search